# How to use char.TryParse with a string

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to use my GetChar method to keep displaying the prompt and reading whatever the user typed on the keyboard until Char.TryParse can convert the input to an char But I keep getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type char to string when I call my GetChar method and I would like to be able to use GetChar with my user input

Any help would be appreciated

```
//Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
    static void ProcessCreate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)

    {
        string message;
        //Int32 player = 0;

        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            try
            {
                message = ("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
                number = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                //(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number Must Be Postive");
            }
            if (GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount) == -1)
            {
                message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name");
                firstName = IOConsole.GetChar(message);
                  //Console.ReadLine();
                message = ("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's Last  Name");
                lastName = IOConsole.GetChar(message);
                 //Console.ReadLine();
                message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals");

                try
                {
                    goals = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                    //Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    message = ("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's assists");
                    assists = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number Must Be Postive");
            }

                InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
              players[player].Number, players[player].FirstName, players[player].LastName,
              players[player].Goals, players[player].Assists, players[player].Points());


                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

    }
```

> Here is my GetChar method

```
 public static char GetChar(string prompt)
    {


        char validChar;

        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        while (!Char.TryParse(input.Key.ToString(), out validChar))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry - try again.");

            Console.Write(prompt);
        }

        return validChar;
    }
```

Comment: Your `GetChar` correctly (based on the name) read single character. It is definitely not a string. You can do `GetChar("...").ToString()` to avoid error and get something like `"A"`, but I strongly suspect you expect some other result from `GetChar` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code implementation, it seems that you are calling `GetChar` function specifically to get the string inputs. However, your function is only able to return 1 character at a time. And as you are trying to cast the char directly to a string, you are getting that error. I am sure this is not what you wanted. If you replace your GetChar code with the following, that should work for you:

```
public static string GetString(string prompt)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            // you may also want to do other input validations here
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry - try again.");
            Console.Write(prompt);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a string may be an arbitrary amount of characters, you cannot implicitly cast it to a `char`. You would need to either change this part `input.Key.ToString()` to `input.KeyChar` or do something like this `input.Key.ToString().ToCharArray()[0]`